How do I find the eigenstates of the dispersion in a diatomic linear chain with two different spring constants?
This is my first post.
I've got a problem with finding the eigenstates of the diatomic linear chain. Let me show you guys what I already did. The equations of motion are:
$$
M_1\ddot u_n^1=-C_1(u_n^1-u_n^2)-C_2(u_n^1-u_{n-1}^2) \\
M_2\ddot u_n^2=-C_1(u_n^2-u_n^1)-C_2(u_n^2-u_{n+1}^2)
$$
Where $u_n^1$ is the position of the atom $A$ in the position $n$, $u_n^2$ for atom $B$; $C_1$ and $C_2$ are the spring constants for the A-B and B-A bonds, respectively.
Proposing solutions like $u_1=\nu_1\exp{i(kna-\omega t)}$ and $u_2=\nu_2\exp{i(kna-\omega t)}$; and considering the periodic boundery conditions ($u_{n+m} = u_n\exp{(ikma)}$), we can solve the system and
$$
-M_1\omega^2\nu_1+C_1(\nu_1-\nu_2)+C_2(\nu_1-\nu_2\exp{(-ika)})=0\\
-M_2\omega^2\nu_2+C_1(\nu_2-\nu_1)+C_2(\nu_2-\nu_1\exp{(ika)})=0
$$
If necessary, I can show the steps I did to find these equations. Solving this system we get:
$M_1M_2\omega^4-(M_1+M_2)(C_1+C_2)\omega^2+2C_1C_2(1-\cos(ka))=0$
After some calculations, we find the dispersion relation:
$$
w^2_\pm (k)=\frac{\omega^2_{\text{máx}}}{2}\left[1\pm \sqrt{1-\gamma^2\sin^2{(ka/2)}}\right]
$$
with the substitutions $2C_+=(C_1+C_2)$ and $C^2_\times=C_1C_2$ (same for $M_1$ and $M_2$):
$$
\frac{\omega^2_{\text{máx}}}{2}=2\frac{M_+C_+}{M^2_\times};\\
\gamma^2=\frac{M_\times^2C_\times^2}{M_+^2C_+^2}
$$
So, the problem asks to find the eigenstates for the case when $M_1=M_2=M$. The dispersion relation changes to:
$$
\omega^2_\pm = 2\frac{C_+}{M}\left[1\pm \sqrt{1-\frac{C_\times^2}{C_+^2}\sin^2{(ka/2)}}\right]
$$
In the border of the zone $k=\pm\pi/a=X$:
$$
\omega^2\pm(X)=\frac{C_1+C_1\pm\left|C_1+C_2\right|}{M}
$$
thus:
$$
\omega^2_+(X)=2\max{(C_1,C_2)/M}\\
\omega^2_-(X)=2\min{(C_1,C_2)/M}
$$
The book (Grundmann) give the answer, but I'm having trouble to interpret the notation, and the steps to achieve it. Could you people help me? Not by giving me the answer, but clarifying the notation and with some insights of how to get there; also, sorry for the english, it is not my native language. Thank you, in advance!
Answer:
$$
\nu_\pm (k) = \begin{pmatrix} \nu_{\pm,1}(k)\\ \nu_{\pm,2}(k)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \mp \frac{C_1+C_2\exp{(ika)}}{\sqrt{C_1^2+C_2^2+2C_1C_2\cos{(ka)}}}\end{pmatrix}
$$
